# how to set sessionAttributes in spring and access them in different jsps and controllers

Tags: java, spring, session

I am a beginner in spring&java. How do i properly pass UserDetailedInfo model into SessionAttrtibutes to access it in different controllers and different jsps?
I am trying to create a login system using spring framework.

```
//this is my mainpagecontroller.java
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("model")
public class MainPageController{   

    @RequestMapping(value="/signin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object>  userSignIn(@RequestParam Map<String,String>  param, ModelMap sessions) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        FormHelpers helper = new FormHelpers();
         Map<String, Object> resp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        resp.put("status", helper.signIn(param).getError());
        sessions.addAttribute("model",resp);

        System.out.println(resp);
        //System.out.println(info.get);
        return resp;
    }
}   

//formhelpers.java
public UserDetailedInfo signIn(Map<String, String> data) {
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

      SigninModel model = new SigninModel();
      model.setEmail(data.get("email"));
      model.setPassword(data.get("password"));
      params.put("email", model.getEmail());
      params.put("password", model.getPassword());
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String response = GlobalHelper.callService(RestServicesUrl.SIGNIN_URL, params);
        UserDetailedInfo info =  mapper.readValue(response, UserDetailedInfo.class);
        System.out.println("error"+info.getError());
        return info;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new UserDetailedInfo();
    }
}

//singedinhomepagecontroller.java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/main")
@SessionAttributes("model")
public class SignedInHomePageController
{
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView displaySignInHomePage(@ModelAttribute FormHelpers model)
    {   
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("homepage");
        System.out.println(model.signIn().getEmail()); //unable to access the from session
        return view;
     }

}
```

//home.jsp

Comment: Its better just to add one question at time.

Comment: Okay will edit to ask only one question!

Answer (score 1):

Use http session on parameters and set atributte and get atribute methods

```
public ModelAndView test(HttpSession session) 
{
      session.setAttribute("success" , "successfully accessed");
}
```

then in other controller method

```
public ModelAndView test(HttpSession session) 
{
      String sessionVar = session.getAttribute("success");
}
```

about creating a login system I will recomend to use http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Comment: Can i pass objects to it? session.setAttribute("success", helper) - from my main controller? I guess there is no point of using @sessionAttributes?

Comment: yes you cant put on session any object that you want. You can use @sessionAttributes in this way http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/session-attributes-annotation.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was able to make it work using sessionAttributes and it was was easy for my layout. But I am still confused between seesionAttributes vs httpsession. I know that one of them is spring and the other one is just based on http.

Comment: session atributtes are all the the object that we save on the session, the http session its the Java EE implementation. There is also session and session atributes on any programing lenguages. spring just put the session on your method atributes. In not spring app you probably have to use request.getSession(). do not fotget to mark as answer x)